# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)\otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ isn't a field.

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I have the following problem:

In our script there is an example stating: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)\otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ isn't a field. But it isn't proven and I don't know how to do it. Can someone explain that to me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us make some distinction, denote
$$
\begin{aligned}
x &= \sqrt 2\otimes 1\ ,\\
y &= 1\otimes \sqrt 2\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Then the given ring is a vector space of dimension four over $\Bbb Q$, with basis $1$, $x$, $y$, $xy$. Now let us look at:
$$ (x+y)(x-y)=x^2-y^2=2\otimes 1-1\otimes 2=0\ .$$
(The elements $x\pm y$ are not zero.)

Comment: +1: as an alternative, using Dan's notation, you could observe that $\pm x$ and $\pm y$ give four distinct roots for the quadratic polynomial $x^2 -2$, but in a field, a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ distinct roots.